My android studio doesn't recognize video and mp3 files, what should I do in the raw file with a question mark next to the file?
My android studio doesn't recognize video and mp3 files, what should I do in the raw file with a question mark next to the file?
I wrote the name correctly, I have Android 2024.1.2 and the Compose and XML projects are together

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My question is exactly the same, android studio does not recognize video and mp3 files in the raw file, while the file exists, there is a question mark label on it.

Repeating yourself doesn't help - you should edit your question to improve it (instead of replying to a comment of a bot). And keep in mind that this website is for programming issues, not merely using programs in general.
